# How do I resize image jpg/png files in AIX based systems through linux commands (Not UNIX)

Tags: aix, image-manipulation, oracle

How do I resize image jpg/png files in AIX based systems through linux commands (Not UNIX).
I have already seen ImageMagick tool in many forums but it's only for unix based systems like ubuntu but it is not working for my system which is AIX based. This is for an Oracle Apps host  Concurrent program where we need to reduce the image dimensions. All the image files are stored in a server directory and need to resize all of them to a specific dimensions. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused how you're accessing the AIX systems "through linux commands". Are you looking for a tool on an AIX system to do the job, or are you trying to mount the AIX files on a Linux system?

Answer (score 1):

The AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications page lists ImageMagick among the available tools:

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/aix-toolbox-linux-applications-downloads-alpha#I

... so I would suggest downloading and installing those RPMs.

Comment: This looks promising. Thank you Jeff. I will check out this tool for my system and will post the results. Thanks much.